# What is the best way to learn RSpec and Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

What is the best way to learn RSpec and Rails3?

I have written JUnit/NUnit test codes, but writing RSpec for Rails3 application is difficult for me.

Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial Book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial).

Comment: That looks good. I can learn on line!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this way is best but it helped me to learn RSpec. 
First understand the Architecture of rails components.You can start
[here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-mvc-architecture)

Then you have the documentation on how to RSpec the rails controller,model,view [here.](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know those resources. Learning architecture is important!